# give detailed steps for installation of beautifulsoup for python to use in notepad++

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can anyone give me the detailed answer on hoe to install beautifulsoup on python. i tried to download it but got the following traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\Programs\first_code.py", line 6, in 
    from BeautifulSoup import *
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

**Can anyone give detailed steps to follow!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) you use import wrong way.
Should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: can you please give me the installation steps